# Why does parameter binding succeed with no arguments when there is one parameter set but fails with two?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have two functions.  The first has one parameter set, the second has two parameter sets as follows:

```
function OneSet{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( $NoSet,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'A')]$A )
    process { $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName }
}

function TwoSets{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( $NoSet,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'A',Mandatory = $true)]$A,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'B',Mandatory = $true)]$B  )
    process { $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName }
}
```

Invoking the first one without arguments results in '__AllParameterSets' binding:

```
C:\> OneSet
__AllParameterSets
```

Invoking the second one without arguments throws an exception:

```
C:\> TwoSets
TwoSets : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
+ TwoSets
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [TwoSets], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,TwoSets
```

I don't see why the second case is any more ambiguous than the first.  Why doesn't PowerShell bind to `TwoSets` using the "`__AllParameterSets`" parameter set?

Is there a (terse) way to have multiple parameter sets and still be able to call the function with no arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I think `None` could be substituted for `__AllParameterSets` to achieve the goal of "creating a parameter set with no mandatory parameters at all".  For more details see [PowerShell/PowerShell#11237](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11237), [#12619](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12619), and [#11143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11143)

---

> I don't see why the second case is any more ambiguous than the first. Why doesn't PowerShell bind to TwoSets using the "`__AllParameterSets`" parameter set?

PowerShell seems to use the `__AllParameterSets` parameter set as a default when there is only one user-named parameter set.  On the other hand, when there is more than one user-named parameter set, PowerShell does not seem to consider any parameter set to be a default unless you specify it.

> Is there a (terse) way to have multiple parameter sets and still be able to call the function with no arguments?

You can tell PowerShell to use `__AllParameterSets` as the default as follows:

```
function TwoSets{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = '__AllParameterSets')]
    param ( $NoSet,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'A', Mandatory = $true)]$A,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'B', Mandatory = $true)]$B  )
    process { $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName }
}
```

Then invoking with no parameters, `-A`, or `-B` yields causes binding to the each of the three parameter sets as follows:

```
PS C:\> TwoSets
__AllParameterSets

PS C:\> TwoSets -A 'a'
A

PS C:\> TwoSets -B 'b'
B
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because PowerShell can't figure out which parameter set you're trying to use.  You can tell it what to default to in the CmdletBinding attribute.

```
function TwoSets{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='A')]
    param ( $NoSet,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'A')]$A,
            [parameter(ParameterSetName = 'B')]$B  )
    process { $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName }
}
```

Comment: Hmm...this method requires that there be no mandatory parameters in parameter set `A`.  I'm going to edit my question to hopefully make it clearer.